# LBG algorithm - can I use existing k-means algorithm for it?

Tags: c#, algorithm

I'm writing a program comparing the working of k-means and LBG algorithm.

I have a k-means algorithm written, which accepts a list of Points and number of clusters, and then draws them on the screen in different colors. It returns me a list of clusters which have a list of points assigned to them.

Now, my question is: can I somehow modify my k-means to get LBG algorithm? I tried searching online for a step by step explanation of LBG, but wikipedia only has 3 sentences on it, I've found mathlab explanation which consists of 4 lines of code, and the original paper which you have to buy. Could someone explain/point me to a guide for this?

Thank you.

Edit: Please, no very hard technical papers, I can't read them properly yet with my english.

Edit2: Here is code for my k-means class:

```
public class k_means
{
    public static List<Punktyzbior> oblicz(Punktyzbior punkty, int klasterctr)
    {
        List<Punktyzbior> wszystkieklastry = new List<Punktyzbior>();
        List<List<Punkt>> wszystkiegrupy = pomocnicze_listy.PodzielListe<Punkt>(punkty, klasterctr);
        foreach (List<Punkt> grupa in wszystkiegrupy)
        {
            Punktyzbior klaster = new Punktyzbior();
            klaster.AddRange(grupa);
            wszystkieklastry.Add(klaster);
        }

        int przejscia = 1;
        while (przejscia > 0)
        {
            przejscia = 0;

            foreach (Punktyzbior klaster in wszystkieklastry)
            {
                for (int punktIdx = 0; punktIdx < klaster.Count; punktIdx++)
                {
                    Punkt punkt = klaster[punktIdx];

                    int najblizszyklaster = znajdzNajblizszy(wszystkieklastry, punkt);
                    if (najblizszyklaster != wszystkieklastry.IndexOf(klaster))
                    {
                        if (klaster.Count > 1)
                        {
                            Punkt usunPunkt = klaster.usunPunkt(punkt);
                            wszystkieklastry[najblizszyklaster].dodajPunkt(usunPunkt);
                            przejscia += 1;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return (wszystkieklastry);
    }

    public static int znajdzNajblizszy(List<Punktyzbior> wszystkieklastry, Punkt punkt)
    {
        double minOdl = 0.0;
        int najblizszyCIdx = -1;

        for (int k = 0; k < wszystkieklastry.Count; k++)
        {
            double odl = Punkt.znajdzOdl(punkt, wszystkieklastry[k].c);
            if (k == 0)
            {
                minOdl = odl;
                najblizszyCIdx = 0;
            }
            else if (minOdl > odl)
            {
                minOdl = odl;
                najblizszyCIdx = k;
            }
        }

        return (najblizszyCIdx);
    }
}
```

Comment: You have to show some code and what you have tried, this is not a site to get people do stuff for you.

Comment: Ok i can add code for k-means. I'm not asking for a complete code, just pointing in direction of link with not very technical explanation in english, or just an explain on what would I need to modify. I mean I can't find good explanation I can understand of LBG myself.

Comment: @LuisTellez ok so I ask question, show code, and I get only minus points in few minutes because I'm not good in english. Why is this question wrong?

Comment: You get the minus points because it does not seem like you have tried anything, and this is a site to solve problems not to stuff for free. Going from k_means to LBG does not seen like the right way to go.

Comment: @LuisTellez I'm trying to find on internet a explanation how LBG algorithm works, but I can't find anything that is not technical hard english paper. I'm asking if someone can point me to a link with easier explanation because I can't find on google. Or tell me if I can modify my code to do LBG. Again I want to write this myself, but I don't understand the hard english papers very well.

I'm trying searching lbg algorithm step by step, lbg algorithm explanation, lbg algorithm from k-means, lbg algorithm c# and can't find.

Comment: I'm not a english native speaker eaither, and no one is down voting you for your english.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of trying to get from kmeans to LBG I would rather try to "translate" this java code to c#, it would be a lot easier I think.

Try to do it, and if you have a specific problem with the implementation come back and let us know.

https://github.com/internaut/JGenLloydCluster/blob/master/src/net/mkonrad/cluster/GenLloyd.java

Comment: Ok, I will try. Thank you, it easier from code than from paper.

Comment: Ok, Im not using java at all, can you clarify is: for (double[] samplePoint : samplePoints) the same as C# foreach(double[] samplePoint in samplePoints)? Thank you.

Comment: Ok, last question:

I managed to convert the code so it's working. However, it only works up to 4 centers; if i try to pick 5 or more, it throws exception of going out of index for array here:

      relClusterWeight[clusterPointIdx] = (double)num / (double)samplePoints.Length;

in function splitClusters(). Any idea why please?

Comment: create a new question with that problem, and paste the code you are using now so we can take a look at it.

Comment: But it happend because you probably declared relClusterWeight of a Size and clusterPointIdx is bigger that what you declared.